# Ограничение suggest по границам карты для вложенных зон

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Прошу помочь в следующей ситуации:

Карту требуется ограничивать по границам определенных зон (Нижегородская, Владимирская, Московская + Москва).
Соответственно, просмотр карты и поиск через suggest должен идти только в рамках этих зон.
Привожу часть кода, которая отвечает за эти действия:

```
// ограничение границ на карте
var AVAILABLE_REGIONS = ['RU-IVA', 'RU-VLA', 'RU-NIZ', 'RU-MOS', 'RU-MOW'];
  ymaps.borders.load('RU', {
                            // lang: 'en'
                        }).then(function (geojson) {
                            var geoObjectCollections = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({}, {visible : false});

                            t.map.geoObjects.add(geoObjectCollections);

                            for (var i = 0; i < geojson.features.length; i++) {
                                if (AVAILABLE_REGIONS.includes(geojson.features[i].properties.iso3166)) {

                                    geoObjectCollections.add(new ymaps.GeoObject(geojson.features[i]));
                                }
                            }
                            t.map.options.set('restrictMapArea', geoObjectCollections.getBounds());

                            t.map.geoObjects.remove(geoObjectCollections);
                            geoObjectCollections.removeAll();
                        });

//настройки suggest
ymaps.suggest(request.term, {
                                    boundedBy: map._restrictMapArea._restrictBounds,
                                    json: true,
                                    strictBounds: true
                                })
                                    .then(successCallback)
                                    .catch(err => {
                                        console.log(err); 
                                        response([]);
                                    });
```

Проблема заключается в том, что suggest, в таком случае, не ищет результаты для Москвы. Вероятно, это связано с тем, что Москва "обернута" в границы Московской области и это каким-то образом ограничивает поиск в той области, которая не входит в границы МО, содержащиеся в массиве, но содержится внутри этих границ по факту.

Прошу подсказать, как можно, не снимая ограничения с поиска по карте, включить Москву в ответы suggest?

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент единственным способом ограничить область поиска по карте является параметр boundedBy https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/doc/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/

То есть то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, в API не документировано и вообще работать не должно.

Comment: Полагаю, свойство strictBounds можно отбросить - думаю, API карт его просто "проглатывает" и не воспринимает.

Но ведь Москва входит в прямоугольную область, которая очерчена через boundedBy. Соответственно, результаты должны возвращаться.
Если бы речь шла о регионе, который выходил бы за рамки прямоугольной области (пример: прямоугольник Владимирская-Ивановская-Нижегородская области и Владивосток, который совершенно явно не граничит с данным прямоугольником),
но здесь мы имеем регион, который целиком и полностью содержится в прямоугольнике.